# Error reading an ObjectInputStream of weka classifier model after building jar file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, weka

I've built an SVM model and saved the model file to be used later for classification directly without rebuilding model again using this method:
https://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization

Now, I want to use this model to classify instances that are obtained from table using HiveQl. So, I have to convert my java project to a jar file to be used as a User Defined Function within hive.

The problem is that when I add this line

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new
FileInputStream("svm.model"));
```

an exception occurs even I've added the svm.model file in the project directory that I export to jar file.

The project directory is:

```
-SVMTweet
  ---referenced libraries
  ---JRE system library
  ---svm.model
  ---src
  -----default package
  -------myclass.java
```

here is my java code: ideone.com/3E2Xgw

here is my hive query + exception returned: pastebin.com/h8ZMDwVe

Is there any mistake in the way I'm trying to use?

Comment: which exception occurs?

Comment: here is my java code
[https://ideone.com/3E2Xgw]

here is my hive query + exception return
https://pastebin.com/h8ZMDwVe

Comment: the link to your java code is not working (404). But you can edit your question and add it directly.

Comment: question edited... there is wrong square bracket at end of the link